# Prevent multiple DOM searches in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a function to return me a jquery element.

```
function GetDialogButton() {
    return $('a.dialog');
};
```

This was done as the same element was used within multiple other functions. I thought it best if it was obtained from a single place, therefore making it easier to change in future should the atribute name change.

I would like to improve this getter so that it does not perform a search everytime when called multiple times within a single page load.

How can I do this? do I cache it? or perhaps there is no need as this is optimised out?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a cache variable, but it will pollute the global namespace again

```
var dialogButton;
function GetDialogButton() {
    if(dialogButton){
        return dialogButton;
    }

    dialogButton = $('a.dialog');
    return dialogButton;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems like my problem would be fairly common, it this a standard way of solving it?

Answer (score 2):

Creating a global cache variable is not necessary. You can do it without adding a variable to the global scope. Something like this would do:

```
var GetDialogButton = (function() {
    var set;

    return function() {
        if (set === undefined) {
            set = $('a.dialog');
        }

        return set;
    };
}());
```

Comment: But that *is* a cache variable?

Comment: @Bergi Indeed, that was poorly worded.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could [lazy-load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) it.

```
var $dialogButton = null;

function GetDialogButton() {
    if($dialogButton == null)
      $dialogButton = $('a.dialog');
    return $dialogButton
};
```

Another alternative, if you expect there to only be one dialog button you could give the element an id and then the act of searching for it will be more efficient

```
<a id="dialogButton">...</a>

$('#dialogButton')... // nice and quick
```

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the global namespace clean by;

```
function GetDialogButton() {
    if (typeof GetDialogButton.element === 'undefined' ) {
        GetDialogButton.element = $("a.dialog");
    }
    return GetDialogButton.element;
};
```

Comment: what if the `GetDialogButton` (which is global variable I suppose) is undefined?

Comment: GetDialogButton is the function itself (a function is an object so can have properties) If it could be undefined you could never call it in the first place.